# TextField not allowing editing

Tags: ios4

I dragged and dropped a TextField from [Interface Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder), in the Navigation Base Project, but it's not allowing me to enter text.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you did not "uncheck"  "user interaction enabled" in interface builder. You can override this with the line of code below in case you cant find the check box.

```
myTextField.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans.
Yes i verified that, its "checked", so thats not the case, the problem exists. When i do it in a view based application, it works fine. I Think its the issue with navigation based application. What should be done now??